# How to widen UIActionSheet to fit the text in iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet

I'm using `UIActionSheet` in a landscape mode application in `iPad`. Some of my button's texts don't fit the width and they're cropped from the end. In `iPhone` this is handled and my action sheet buttons fit into the frame even if they are long. I didn't understand why this is different in iPad. Do you guys have any ideas about how I can accomplish something as `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` method does to `UILabel`s?

Here's how I create and display my action sheet:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

for (NSString *bank in self.getBanksResponse.banks) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:bank];
}

[actionSheet showFromRect:self.bankButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
[actionSheet release];
```

Here's the screenshot of my action sheet:

[image]

Thx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine - I have two ideas for you:

1) In the showFromRect method called from your actionsheet, edit the passed in rect to be wider and see how it goes.

2) If the above did not work, then you might want to look into subclassing it to accommodate your text... or look at UIPopoverController which could hold your data in a table view.

Comment: I tried giving the sheet a wider frame than my button's frame but this time the action sheet was shifted horizontally, i mean it's width did not change. If no one has any other ideas, I guess I'll go along with your second advice. Thx Krypton!

Comment: Definitely go with the second part of my point 2), and remember that UIPopoverController is iPad-only. UIActionSheets are generally iPhone-only, so be sure to perform a device check if your app is universal.

Comment: OK, that would be better, I agree. The app is iPad only, so I'll be safe :)